# Compiling for PIC16F with SDCC: on RPi: libsdcc.lib: no such file or directory

Tags: sdcc

I've compiled SDCC 3.7.0 on a Raspberry Pi 2. But I'm having diffuculty with the next step: compiling a blink.c *with* SDCC:

```
sdcc -mpic14 -p16f887 blink.c --use-non-free
```

It just returns "libsdcc.lib: no such file or directory". Please help!

Comment: Have you seen this thread? https://sourceforge.net/p/piklab/discussion/633023/thread/a76d7da1/ looks relevant

Comment: Thanks, will try installing newest gputils now then! Real coincidence since this is how I compiled sdcc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49717240/

Comment: Let me know if it works and i'll post it as an answer, extra rep is always nice :)

Comment: dpkg -l gputils says it's already at v1.4.0, that link discussed v0.13.4, and is unlikely to benefit from compiling v1.6? (as mentioned here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82714). What I dont understand is how reports over the net of others apparently using SDCC on RPi without these hurdles. I swear Linux hates me

Comment: There was a fedora bug report here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=454205 that seems to be implying sdcc isnt helpful without the pic libraries, i'm not quite sure what all that means, but are you sure you have all the libraries you need? This may make more sense to you than me

Comment: I'm wondering if you found the solution. I'm getting the same error after compiling gputils 1.5.2 and sdcc 4.2.0 on termux on android and trying to compile blink example.